# Where's the "TEMP" folder for Custom Build Steps?

Tags: visual-c++, batch-file, custom-build-step

Visual Studio 2010, in my project I made a custom build step which renames a dll file and copies it to other folder. So, Alt+F7, Config props, Custom Build Step / General, command line:

```
    copy /y $(TargetPath) $(TargetName).node
```

It didn't do anything. Then I also added

```
    ping bat.femei.ro -n 1 -w 5000
```

It still didn't do anything. It simply flashed a command prompt window for a split second then the window went away. I googled as much as I could concluding that there might be a problem with the folder where the batch file is generated.

I did my best to screenshot that split second with the command prompt and after a boring F7-PrintScreen-PasteInPaint session finally I got

`C:\Users\FURAT\AppData\Local\Temp\blablablablablablablablabla.exec.cmd is not recognized as internal or external...`

I double checked the directory. It has `Everyone` permissions set to Allow both Read & Write operations. What's wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: Also to mention I tried disabling Avast. Still nothing.

Comment: Do you can show the exact path/filename, perhaps it's a problem with special characters/white spaces in the name

Comment: @jeb exact output: `'C:\Users\FURAT\AppData\Local\Temp\5be2d73ba2b1444fa45a62292db9b045.exec.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find any knobs to tweak temp folder path. It's not Env and it's not in the config either.

What did work however was running VS2010 as Administrator. Now the Custom Build Step works.